# Trying to run a for loop in R to create several graphs at once. The graphs come out blank but every section of the code runs well on its own

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2, graph, charts

relatively new to R (and programming in general) and am trying to use a for loop to generate several graphs at once. The GeneModules object is basically a dataframe of 24 modules (each module as its own column) with different numbers of genes in each. I am trying to submit them to an online database, calculate the -log of the adjusted P-Value for each row, and make a graph of the results. I have the first three loops working perfectly, and while the fourth (under '#Make graphs') does not produce any error message, the pdf file does not open as if it were blank. When I have tried running the ggplot code outside of a loop on just the tmp file that was left at the end of the loop, it worked perfectly. I would ideally like to learn how to automate the graph production, though. My code looks like this:

```
#Separate each Gene Module into separate dataframes
for(i in 1:ncol(GeneModules)){
  tmp <- subset(GeneModules[i])
  tmp <- tmp[!is.na(tmp)]
  tmp <- as.data.frame(tmp)
  write.table(tmp,
              file= file.path('~/Desktop/Scripts/Meninges_scRNA/Output/', paste0('Module',i,'.csv')),
              sep=',',
              row.names=FALSE)
}

#Run each module df through EnrichR to find terms and P-values
for(i in 1:ncol(GeneModules)){
  tmp <- read.csv(file=file.path('~/Desktop/Scripts/Meninges_scRNA/Output/', paste0('Module',i,'.csv')))
  enriched <- enrichr(tmp[[1]], dbs)
  write.table(enriched$GO_Biological_Process_2021,
              file= file.path('~/Desktop/Scripts/Meninges_scRNA/Output/', paste0('BP_Module',i,'.csv')),
              sep=',',
              row.names=FALSE)
  write.table(enriched$GO_Cellular_Component_2021,
              file= file.path('~/Desktop/Scripts/Meninges_scRNA/Output/', paste0('CC_Module',i,'.csv')),
              sep=',',
              row.names=FALSE)
  write.table(enriched$GO_Molecular_Function_2021,
              file= file.path('~/Desktop/Scripts/Meninges_scRNA/Output/', paste0('MF_Module',i,'.csv')),
              sep=',',
              row.names=FALSE)
  write.table(enriched$WikiPathway_2021_Human,
              file= file.path('~/Desktop/Scripts/Meninges_scRNA/Output/', paste0('WP_Module',i,'.csv')),
              sep=',',
              row.names=FALSE)
}

#Find -log10(adj. P) 
for (i in 1:ncol(GeneModules)) {
  tmp <- read_csv(file= file.path('~/Desktop/Scripts/Meninges_scRNA/Output/', paste0('BP_Module',i,'.csv')))
  tmp$LOG <- with(tmp, (-log10(tmp$Adjusted.P.value)))
  tmp <- as_tibble(tmp)
  tmp %>% arrange(desc(LOG))
  tmp <- as.data.frame(tmp)
  assign(paste0('tmp',i), tmp)
  write.table(tmp,
              file= file.path('~/Desktop/Scripts/Meninges_scRNA/Output/', paste0('BP_Module',i,'.csv')),
              sep=',',
              row.names=FALSE)
}

#Make graphs
pdf(file = file.path('~/Desktop/Scripts/Meninges_scRNA/Output/BP_Modules.pdf'))
for (i in 1:ncol(GeneModules)) {
  tmp <- read_csv(file= file.path('~/Desktop/Scripts/Meninges_scRNA/Output/', paste0('BP_Module',i,'.csv')))
  tmp <- head(tmp, 10)
  ggplot(data=tmp, aes(x=Term, y=LOG)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="navy", alpha=.95, width=0.8) +
    scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0.00001)) + 
    scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0,0)) +
    coord_flip() +
    ylab("-Log(Adj. P-Value)") +
    xlab("") +
    theme_bw() +
    geom_hline(yintercept = 1.28, color = "green", size=.3) +
    theme(
      axis.text.x=element_text(),
      axis.text.y=element_text(face = "bold", size = 14),
      plot.title = element_text(color="Black", size=14, face="bold", hjust=0.5)) +
    ggtitle(paste0("2021 GO Biological Processes of Module ", i))
}
dev.off()
```

Please help me figure out what the issue is here. I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured it out. When in for loops ggplot requires a print() function.

Writing as:

```
print(ggplot(data=tmp, aes(x=Term, y=LOG)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="navy", alpha=.95, width=0.8) +
    scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0.00001)) + 
    scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0,0)) +
    coord_flip() +
    ylab("-Log(Adj. P-Value)") +
    xlab("") +
    theme_bw() +
    geom_hline(yintercept = 1.28, color = "green", size=.3) +
    theme(
      axis.text.x=element_text(),
      axis.text.y=element_text(face = "bold", size = 14),
      plot.title = element_text(color="Black", size=14, face="bold", hjust=0.5)) +
    ggtitle(paste0("2021 GO Biological Processes of Module ", i)))
```

Fixed the issue!